# React Sanity Blog Configuration with Support to Import to Medium

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blogs, sanity

I hope you're having a great day. I am about to add a blog to my react portfolio website using Sanity.io. I want to configure the blog/sanity in such a way that I am able to use Medium's import feature to automatically import my article from my blog to my Medium account. I've attempted importing other Sanity blogs I found online into Medium and I noticed that some import correctly while others do not.

Are there any best practices when setting up and/or configuring my react sanity blog that I should be aware of. Before I build my react blog, I want to make sure it will support the import feature on Medium.

Let me know if you have any suggestions or resources. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export your content from Sanity to Medium, it looks like [Medium's API](https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs) can handle it. You could configure a [document action](https://www.sanity.io/docs/document-actions) in your studio that would let you send your blog article.

If you're looking to use Medium's import post feature, then whether it works or not will depend more on your front end than on Sanity. I just tested it with a Next.js front end, and it appeared to work just fine.